# Warning message on arguments expectation

Tags: c, char, integer, warnings

I seem to have this warning on my compiler [Warning] format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]. I don't quite understand it says argument 2 has type 'int' because I think the data type was supposed to be 'char'. Does anyone know why my code has this warning?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int ID;
    char model;
    float price;
}car;

car cardetails[5];

int main()
{
    
    int i;
    
    for (i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    {
        printf("\nCar[%d] ID: ", i); 
        scanf("%d", &cardetails[i].ID);
        
        printf("Car[%d] Model: ", i); 
        scanf("%s", &cardetails[i].model);
        
        printf("Car[%d] Price: ", i); 
        scanf("%f", &cardetails[i].price);
    }
    
    float average = 0;
    
    for (i = 1; i < 6; i++){
        average =+ cardetails[i].price;
    }
    
    average = average / 5;
    
    for(i = 1; i < 6; i++){
        printf("Car ID: %d", cardetails[i].ID);
        printf("Model: %s", cardetails[i].model);
        printf("Price: %f", cardetails[i].price);
        i = i + 2;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `char model;` can only hold a single character; model names usually consist of more than one character.  You need `char model[32];` or some such definition.

The `printf("Model: %s", cardetails[i].model)` line passes the single character to `printf()`, but the `%s` tells `printf()` to expect a `char *`.

The reference to `int` occurs because values passed to a variadic function are default promoted, and `char` in particular gets promoted to `int` automatically.  See the C standard [§6.5.2.2 Function calls ¶6](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p6):

> ¶6 If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that have type `float` are promoted to `double`. These are called the *default argument promotions*. If the number of arguments does not equal the number of parameters, the behavior is undefined. If the function is defined with a type that includes a prototype, and either the prototype ends with an ellipsis (`, ...`) or the types of the arguments after promotion are not compatible with the types of the parameters, the behavior is undefined. If the function is defined with a type that does not include a prototype, and the types of the arguments after promotion are not compatible with those of the parameters after promotion, the behavior is undefined, except for the following cases:
>
> - one promoted type is a signed integer type, the other promoted type is the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types;
> - both types are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of a character type or `void`.
>
> ¶7 If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does include a prototype, the arguments are implicitly converted, as if by assignment, to the types of the corresponding parameters, taking the type of each parameter to be the unqualified version of its declared type. The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. The default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments.

The *integer promotions* are defined in [§6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters and integers ¶2](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1p2):

> …
> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the *integer promotions*.<sup>58)</sup> All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.
>
> §3 The integer promotions preserve value including sign. As discussed earlier, whether a ''plain'' `char` is treated as signed is implementation-defined.
>
> <sup>58)</sup> 58) The integer promotions are applied only: as part of the usual arithmetic conversions, to certain argument expressions, to the operands of the unary `+`, `-`, and `~` operators, and to both operands of the shift operators, as specified by their respective subclasses.

---

There are other problems in the code too.  You access the array out of bounds, and array indexes start at 0, not 1.

```c
car cardetails[5];

…

    for (i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    {
        printf("\nCar[%d] ID: ", i); 
        scanf("%d", &cardetails[i].ID);
        …
    }

…

    for(i = 1; i < 6; i++){
        printf("Car ID: %d", cardetails[i].ID);
        printf("Model: %s", cardetails[i].model);
        printf("Price: %f", cardetails[i].price);
        i = i + 2;
    }
```

The last loop prints elements `1` and `4` of the array — they happen to be valid indexes — because of the `i++` and the `i = i + 2`.  The first loop goes trampling way beyond the last valid index (which is `cardetails[4]`).  An idiomatic `for` loop in C uses:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    …cardetails[i].whatever…
}
```

where `5` is the number of elements in the array — the loop uses indexes `0` .. `4`.  Ideally, you don't repeat `5`; you use an enumeration or `#define` to define the size of the array.

You should test that each and every call to `scanf()` succeeds, taking appropriate action if not.  You should limit how much data is read with `%31s` (for example, assuming that the array is of size `32`).

I've not run the code past a compiler and there are likely other issues to resolve too.